# Firebase: Send err http error status: 404; reason: app instance has been unregistered; code: registration-token-not-registered

Tags: java, go

I encountered an error when trying to call Firebase using its new get registration token call. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Also, I can no longer directly message in the Firebase console.

This problem:
Send err http error status: 404; reason: app instance has been unregistered; code: registration-token-not-registered; details: Requested entity was not found

I want to someone reply this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.